# SQL Server get Min() from only one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I want to pick the records with the minimum **quantity** per **package_id**

I have these data on **TableA**

```
package_id  group_id    quantity
1013        2           8
1013        3           6
1091        4           4
1091        2           8
1014        4           4
```

and I need to end up to this result

```
package_id  group_id    quantity
1013        3           6
1091        4           4
1014        4           4
```

I cannot have a simple Min() because it would Group By **group_id** as well so I will miss the point.

Thank you

Comment: select t1.package_id, t1.group_id, t1.quantity from tableA t1 inner join (select package_id, min(quantity) qty from tableA group by quantitiy) t2 on t1.package_id = t2.package_id and t1.quantity = t2.qty;

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error: Column 'TableA.package_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @PanosPlat, sorrty that group by would be group by package_id. My bad.